# Error using the reloader flag for bottle framework

Tags: python, virtualenv, bottle

I am creating a website using Python and the Bottle framework for the first time. It is in a directory set up with virtualenv.

I have the hello world website working perfectly, but before continuing development I would like to get auto_reloader working. I have tried adding the `reloader=True` to the run statement:

```
from bottle import run
import corecontrollers

run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
```

However, this fails with the error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\Python Projects\BottleSite\Scripts\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

It looks like a path error. I assume something is going wrong with the virtualenv directory.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Docs say it runs child process when `reloader` is True. May be this is the problem - that child process is running not in virtualenv (no `activate` is called)?

Comment: @demalexx I think you are absolutely correct. However I am not sure how to get the activate bat file to be executed in the child process. I have been looking at the documentation, but not making much progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't find '**main**' module

Why not try the official hello world sample with `reloader=True`:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
@route('/hello/:name')
def index(name = 'World'):
    return '<b>Hello %s!</b>' % name

run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
```